# Ubuntu 18. GNOME Tweaks. Shell themes aren't displayed correctly

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

Had a Ubuntu -> Manjaro (with KDE) -> Ubuntu reinstall, after which I installed `gnome-tweaks`. All went well, until I got to the shell themes topic, where I currently have problems.

Any shell theme I install, 1st from [ubuntupit](https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-15-best-gnome-shell-themes-gnome-desktop/) for example, are drawn as 
[image: example]
where the "black part" is hover, and seems to be the correct part of the theme.

I've tried cleaning the theme directory and reinstalling the "user theme" plugin (GNOME Shell extension).

Comment: Which theme? How did you install the theme? At which directory? What are the other things you did to activate the theme?

Comment: In the example I've used the "Arc Theme". To install it I used the UI of the Gnome-tweaks>Appearance>Shell, which worked fine in the recent past.

Comment: It looks like any theme I install looks the same.

Comment: Well, and after placing new themes manually in ~/.local/share/themes it turned out that all is working correctly. Well, atleast a more specific point to look upon.